# Android ListView padding not working for scrollbar?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-scrollbar

I am developing an android game and in a kind of lobby screen with rooms, i have all the content of the screen inside a giant scroll. Here´s an image of it:
http://postimg.org/image/s64pzkxkz/

The problem is: Even though i put a android:paddingBottom="40sp" on the ListView(to make it a little higher than the bottom of the giant scroll), the scrollbar associated with it is overlapping the giant scroll. There´s a giant gray line that touches the bottom of the scroll... That´s my scrollbar.

Here is the code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/idqualquersotestarlayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"
android:background="@drawable/background_popups_modo_casual" >

<LinearLayout 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/tituloCasual"
            android:background="@drawable/plaquinha_treinamento"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:gravity="center" >

            <TextView 
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:textSize="40sp" 
                android:singleLine="true" 
                android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
                android:text="@string/modo_casual"
                android:id="@+id/textoTituloCasual"/>
</LinearLayout>
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/cordasPlacaCasual"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tituloCasual"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/cordas_placa_treinamento"
    android:layout_marginTop="-5sp" />
 <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/pergaminho"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cordasPlacaCasual"
    android:layout_marginTop="-60sp"
    android:background="@drawable/pergaminho" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/botaoReload"
    style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/botaoCriarNovaSala"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/botaoCriarNovaSala"
    android:text="@string/recarregar"
    android:onClick="recarregarSalas" />

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/spinnerELabelPesquisarSalas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="110sp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/labelPesquisarSalas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
    android:text="@string/pesquisar_salas_por"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/spinnerPesquisarSalasModoCasual"
    android:layout_width="200sp"
    android:layout_height="50sp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/labelPesquisarSalas"
    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/labelPesquisarSalas"/>
</RelativeLayout>
<TextView android:id="@+id/alerta_salas_novas"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/alerta_novas_salas_criadas"
            android:layout_below="@+id/botaoCriarNovaSala"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="28dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:visibility="invisible" />

 <LinearLayout
     android:id="@+id/cabecalho_tabela_listar_salas"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_below="@+id/alerta_salas_novas"
     android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
     android:background="@drawable/red_header"
     android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/lista_salas_abertas"
     android:layout_alignRight="@+id/lista_salas_abertas" >

     <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_titulo_do_jogador"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/dan"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />
    <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_titulo_username"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="3"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/email"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_categorias_selecionadas"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="@string/categorias"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/label_entrar_na_sala"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF" />

</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lista_salas_abertas"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/spinnerELabelPesquisarSalas"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/spinnerELabelPesquisarSalas"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:paddingBottom="40sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/cabecalho_tabela_listar_salas"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:fastScrollAlwaysVisible="true"
    android:scrollbarStyle="insideInset"
    android:listSelector="@android:color/transparent" >
</ListView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/botaoCriarNovaSala"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/spinnerELabelPesquisarSalas"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="abrirTelaCriarNovaSala"
    android:text="@string/criar_nova_sala" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

What can i do to add padding to the scrollbar?

Comment: isn't margin an option for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The height of a ListView is the sum of the heights of it children. So a padding will have no effect on the list. In case you need a margin, you can use marginBottom.

But if you need a space inside the list, you will have to add it to the last child of the list. son in the getView method of the listView adapter you need to add something like this:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    .
    .
    .

    if(position == getCount() - 1){
        view.setPadding(0, 0, 0, 40);
    }

    return view;
}
```

Comment: i have tried to use the marginbottom instead of the padding bottom and for some reason, it is giving me more empty space on the top and not the bottom. I am pretty sure i didn´t switch top with bottom. I Have no idea why it does this.

Comment: oh, i solved the problem. It was just a alignparentbottom="true" i put on the listview. When i removed it and switched the paddingbottom to marginbottom, it worked. Really thank you!!! ^^ Now i just need a solution to my header problem: The header is supposed to be aligned with the listview columns, but since the listview has a scrollbar, the alignment is a little off. I posted my question a while ago at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25735430/android-listview-with-scrollbar-aligned-with-header, but got no good answers ._.